# Search using WP_Query

Tags: search

I'm using the following `WP_Query` within my `search.php` template in order to only search the 'products' custom post type. For some reason, its returning other post types with some search terms.

Any Ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php global $query_string; ?>

<?php $query_args = explode("&", $query_string); ?>

<?php $search_query = array( 'post_type' => 'products', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC' ); ?>

<?php foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {

    $query_split = explode("=", $string);

    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);

} ?>

<?php $search = new WP_Query($search_query); ?>

<?php if ( $search->have_posts() ) : while ( $search->have_posts() ) : $search->the_post(); ?>

<div class="product">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <section>

            <?php if( get_field('product_image') ) { ?>

                <?php $product_image = get_field('product_image'); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $product_image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product_image   ['alt']; ?>" >

            <?php } else { ?>

                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/fallback-image.png" alt="Product image coming soon.">

            <?php } ?>

            <h2><?php trimmed_title('...', 22); ?><br /><span><?php the_field('reference_number'); ?></span></h2>

        </section>
    </a>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>Sorry, no products matched your search criteria.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line -

```
<?php $search_query['post_type'] = 'products'; ?>
```

Just before the line -

```
<?php $search = new WP_Query($search_query); ?>
```

Comment: Still getting the problem, it only seems to apply to searches that are less than 3 characters in length. So for example when searching for animals "an" returns all the unwanted results and "ani" returns the correct results?

Comment: There are stopwords that are stripped from search keyword automatically. - `about,an,are,as,at,be,by,com,for,from,how,in,is,it,of,on,or,that,the,this,to,was,what,when,where,who,will,with,www`

Comment: In this case then it would seem the majority of which are currently working. Why wolud this be?

Comment: It seems that the issue is happening with all terms after all. So it must be something wrong with the WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

Is your CPT registered as "products" or "product"? Usually the singular is used for the type name, and then labels are given for the singular & plural names. Try changing `'post_type' => 'products'` to `'post_type' => 'product'`.

Comment: Its registered as "products", gave it a try but it seemed to remove the "products" post type and leave the unwanted results?